# SQL to show and group by occurrences of multiple column duplicates

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table that looks something like this but with lots of rows:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+---------+
| systemid  | colcitrixid | colleague  |  time |   date    |  week |  period |  year  |  usern  |
| 32855671  |   nameu02   |  somename  | 10:12 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
|
|
|   ...     |     ...     |    ...     |  ...  |    ...    |  ...  |   ...   |  ...   |   ...   |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+---------+
```

(column names summaried and some missed out so it fits in this stackoverflow editor width.)

I would like to run a query to get a list of duplicate rows where the systemid, the colcitrixid and the date are all the same so I can put them into another table to work on.

Here is what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT
    systemid,
    colleaguecitrixid,
    colleague,
    TIME,
    DATE,
    WEEK,
    period,
    fincyear,
    username,
    COUNT(systemid) AS mids,
    COUNT(colleaguecitrixid) AS colleagues,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
FROM
    table_name_2019
WHERE
    period = '9' AND calltype = 'Advice' AND enabled = '1' AND isarchived = '0' AND DATE <> '$todaysdate'
GROUP BY
    systemid,
    colleague,
    DATE
HAVING
    COUNT(systemid) > 1 AND COUNT(colleaguecitrixid) > 1
```

It almost works, but I'm missing something, because it is showing duplicates that include different colleaguecitrixid entries. It's doing it's result based on these rows from the orignal table like so

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+---------+
| systemid  | colcitrixid | colleague  |  time |   date    |  week |  period |  year  |  usern  |
| 32852671  |   nameu02   |  Jack      | 10:12 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
| 32852671  |   nameu02   |  Jack      | 10:14 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name5   |
| 32852671  |   nameu09   |  James     | 10:14 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name5   |
| 34855673  |   nameu05   |  Bob       | 11:18 | 2019-11-03|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name2   |
| 34855673  |   nameu05   |  Bob       | 11:18 | 2019-11-03|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
| 32851672  |   nameu08   |  Sarah     | 13:17 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name2   |
| 32851672  |   nameu08   |  Sarah     | 13:19 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name3   |
| 32851672  |   nameu08   |  Sarah     | 13:21 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name1   |
| 32855671  |   nameu06   |  Jim       | 10:19 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
| 32855671  |   nameu06   |  Jim       | 10:22 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
|   ...     |     ...     |    ...     |  ...  |    ...    |  ...  |   ...   |  ...   |   ...   |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+---------+
```

(Note, row 3, where we see James, a different colleague, but the system id is the same as the rows above with Jack)

but I would like it to only include the ones that are duplicated systemid AND colleaguecitrixid AND date, grouped together a bit like so:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+---------+
| systemid  | colcitrixid | colleague  |  time |   date    |  week |  period |  year  |  usern  |
| 32852671  |   nameu02   |  Jack      | 10:12 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
| 32852671  |   nameu02   |  Jack      | 10:14 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name5   |
| 34855673  |   nameu05   |  Bob       | 11:18 | 2019-11-03|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name2   |
| 34855673  |   nameu05   |  Bob       | 11:18 | 2019-11-03|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
| 32851672  |   nameu08   |  Sarah     | 13:17 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name2   |
| 32851672  |   nameu08   |  Sarah     | 13:19 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name3   |
| 32851672  |   nameu08   |  Sarah     | 13:21 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | name1   |
| 32855671  |   nameu06   |  Jim       | 10:19 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
| 32855671  |   nameu06   |  Jim       | 10:22 | 2019-11-01|   23  |    5    |  2019  | othname |
|   ...     |     ...     |    ...     |  ...  |    ...    |  ...  |   ...   |  ...   |   ...   |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-------+-----------+-------+---------+--------+---------+
```

(I'm showing the rows from the orignal table the result seems to be drawing from above, I understand the result of my query is not formatted like the above, I need the other parts and format of the query for later steps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> systemid, the colcitrixid and the date are all the same

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT systemid, colcitrixid, date, COUNT(*),
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
FROM table_name_2019
WHERE period = '9' AND
      calltype = 'Advice' AND
      enabled = '1' AND isarchived = '0' AND
      DATE <> CURDATE()
GROUP BY systemid, colcitrixid, date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I don't see `colcitrixid` in the data.  If you really mean `colleaguecitrixid`, then use that.

Note:

- In an aggregation query, all columns not in the `GROUP BY` should be arguments to aggregation columns.
- MySQL has a function to return the date.  There is no need to pass that value in under most circumstances.
- The `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT()` is probably unnecessary.  A column called `id` should not have duplicates.

Comment: Thanks.
After putting back some of the other SELECT fields you removed in your answer (I know they are not aggregation columns, and are just results from the first matching row but that is what I want to happen, because I want to use those values in another table to keep track of work done with the duplicates this query finds.)

Comment: @Anseur . . . They ARE NOT results from the "first matching row".  They are values from indeterminate rows, not even guaranteed to be from the same row.

Comment: Intresting. In my case, as the group by date will mean that all matching rows will have very similar data in them, it won't really matter for my use case, but for other situations, how does the database decide which row to serve them from then? If you need the other data (say from the first matching row for instance) would it be best to just run a separate query to get those other fields?

Answer (score 0):

If your DB's version is 10.2+, then consider using

`COUNT(colleaguecitrixid) OVER (PARTITION BY systemid, colleague, date)` analytic function :

```
SELECT systemid,
       colleaguecitrixid,
       colleague,
       time,
       date,
       week,
       period,
       fincyear,
       username,
       mids,
       colleagues,
       ids 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT t.*,      
          COUNT(systemid) AS mids,
          COUNT(colleaguecitrixid) OVER (PARTITION BY systemid, colleague, date) AS colleagues,
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS ids
     FROM table_name_2019 t
    WHERE period = '9' 
      AND calltype = 'Advice' 
      AND enabled = '1' 
      AND isarchived = '0' 
      AND DATE <> '$todaysdate'
  ) t1  
  WHERE colleagues > 1
```